# How to get the data from the database not from the persistentContext.

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I  extracting the list of rows from the database table but  the latest  data of rows are not getting listed in that list until i did not use clear().
 I want to know using em.clear()  is the right or the only way to get the latest data of row from the  database table.
I really  appreciate the reply.

2. em.refresh is work for the single entity but not works for the list of the rows

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Any transactions involved?

Comment: em manages your persistence layer, if you skip it and save data into database, it will not know what happened unless you 'clear' your session, but IMO it is a bad practice. you should let inform em, if you really want to skip it, just use native query, it will work

Comment: @Henry - Using the entityManager i am extracting the list of UsersDetail. Their is another model UserAddress which have many to one relation with UsersDetail. when i am updating the UserAdress using the persist() i am getting the updated information in database table but when i am requesting the  UserDetail information  i am not getting updated information UserAddress in that. I want to know any way by which  if any change is happen in the child table it get automatically update the  parent table  instance in persistent Entity.  both UserDetail  UserAdress have different PersistentEntity

Answer (score 0):

It is because 1 level cache. You need to start new transaction = new persistent context. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lZnBTTbmRQ